# Directory permission check and change

Tags: php, file-permissions

I want a certain directory of file permissions be checked and change if it is different with pre defined value. How can I do this?

```
    $dir ="./";
    $chmod =0644;
     $k=fileperms($dir);
     // $chmod=  decoct(intval($chmod));
     if ( $k!== $chmod) {
         chmod($dir ,$chmod);
    }
```

Note: My problem is not about **chmod** , How can I check present permissions and How can I compare it with my defined value? Because  **fileperms** returns 5 digit (for example 40644) and my defined variable is octal value and four digit (for example 0644).

Comment: Check some of the examples. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php Some of the examples addresses your question.

Comment: @luckytaxi I checked there and googlized sufficiently. My problem is about decimal and octal values changes. Please read end part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to bitwise-and the return value of `fileperms` to get just it's lower bits, and compare that:

```
 // Get only the 4 righmost octal digits of the file's permissions
$perms = fileperms($file) & 07777;
$chmod = 0644;

if ($perms !== $chmod) { 
   // do your stuff
}
```

Note that there are no "octal value" vs. "decimal value" - integers are all integers, and can be represented in differnet notations, so its perfectly fine to compare the "octal" `$chmod` and "decimal" `$perms` - in  reality they are just integers. For example, try to run the following:

```
var_dump(0644);
```

You get `int(420)` because `0644` is just a way to represent the integer value 420 (decimal) in octal notation. For the same reason, this works:

```
var_dump(0644 === 420);
// Output is bool(true)
```

Comment: This answer should help. Forget the first number, just strip it out and use the last four.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, untested as not on my computer at the mo,

```html
<?php

 $dir ="./";
 $chmod =0644;

function chmod_r($dir) {
   $dp = opendir($dir);
        while($Folder = readdir($dp)) {
            if($Folder != "." AND $Folder != "..") {
               if(is_dir($Folder)){
                    if(substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($folder)), -4) !== "0644"){
                chmod($Folder, 0644);
}         
         }
      }
   }
   closedir($dp);
}
chmod_r($dir);
?>
```

Comment: My problem is not about chmod , How can I check present permissions and How can I compare it with my defined value? Because fileperms returns 5 digit (for example 40644) and my defined variable is octal value and four digit (for example 0644).

Comment: chmod($Folder, 0644); must be changed as chmod($Folder, $chmod ); So octal and decimal problem would be appeared.  !== "$chmod" also should be changed.